# Problem with my own libraries and check forms. Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, post, libraries

I have a problem, everything was working but then I tried to put my functions in my own libraries (to use them in different controllers) and it doesn't work.

I have SIGNUP controller with this:

```
$this->load->library('Check_functions');        
// We check the form
$return_verif_form_signup = $this->check_functions->verif_form_signup($language);
```

which calls my librarie Check_functions:

```
class Check_functions {
public function verif_form_signup($language) {
if ($this->input->post()){
// Verification rules
$this->form_validation->set_rules('name', 'lang:name', 'trim|required|xss_clean');
....

if ($this->form_validation->run($this)) {
                extract($_POST);
...
...
}
```

But I get the error:
Fatal error: Call to a member function post() on a non-object

Does anyone know how I could fix it?

thanks!

**EDIT:**

I have found the problem, the callback function is not called. If I replace `callback_free_email` by **REQUIRED** and I don't enter an email, my form is not submitted, so it's okay.
But if I have the following code, my form is always submitted. So the callback function is never called...

This is my code (i'm using **HMVC**):

```
class Check_functions {

private $CI;
public function __construct(){
      $this->CI =& get_instance();
}

public function verif_form_signup($language) {
   if ($this->CI->input->post()){
      $this->CI->form_validation->set_rules('name', 'lang:field_name', 'trim|required|min_length[3]|max_length[25]|xss_clean');
      $this->CI->form_validation->set_rules('email_signup', 'lang:field_email', 'callback_free_email');
...//other rules

        if ($this->CI->form_validation->run($this->CI)) {
         .....
        }
    }
}

public function free_email($str) {
        return FALSE; // I have temporarly set that so I see if my function is called
    }
}
```

I have a file called **MY_Form_validation.php** as suggested here: http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/143057/#769347

```
class MY_Form_validation extends CI_Form_validation{

    function run($module = '', $group = ''){
        (is_object($module)) AND $this->CI = &$module;
            return parent::run($group);
    }

}
```

I really don't know what's wrong... why my callback function is not called?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

when you are writing libraries, you have to manually grab the Codeigniter instance like this

```
$CI =& get_instance();
```

then you would use `$CI` where you would normally use `$this` to interact with loaded codeigniter resources

so...

instead of

```
$this->input->post();
```

you would write

```
$CI->input->post();
```

Docs explain it here http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/creating_libraries.html

***EXAMPLE LIBRARY STRUCTURE***

```
class Examplelib {

    // declare your CI instance class-wide private
    private $CI;

    public function __construct()
    {
        // get the CI instance and store it class wide
        $this->CI =& get_instance();
    }

    public function lib_function()
    {
        // use it here
        $this->CI->db->etc()
    }

    public function another_func()
    {
        // and here
        $this->CI->input->post();
    }

}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the `=&` operator is deprecated in php 5.3

Comment: Codeigniter does not hold a 5.3 requirement

Comment: thanks! Now it works almost, I have a validation rule in Check_functions.php which has a callback: callback_free_email. And downer in the same file I have the callback function which doesn't work anymore: `public function free_email($str) {
   $query = $CI->db->select('email')->from('candidate')->where('email', $str)->get();
  if ($query->num_rows() == 0) {  
   return TRUE;
  }
  else        
   $CI->form_validation->set_message('free_email', 'email already used');
   return FALSE;
 }` It returns TRUE all the time so I guess the query is not working anymore...?

Comment: looks like your missing a few curly braces, especially just after your `else` and then one at the end of your function.

Comment: I have corrected it but i still have the problem (I have adited my first post, it's more clear)

Comment: added to my answer to show how to share the CI instance across multiple functions.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a workaround, instead of using the callback in my rule, I do a test later and call a verification function.
It’s works well like that.
Thanks for your help!